# Will mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification trigger fetchedResultsController's objectsChanged: delegate methods?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsnotifications

I have a setup where in a background thread  I save new objects in managedObjectContext A, in a TableViewController I listen to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and handle the notification like this:

```
- (void) refreshData:(NSNotification *)notif {
   assert([[self fetchedResultsController] managedObjectContext] == self.managedObjectContext);
   if ([notif object] != self.managedObjectContext) {
       [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notif];
   }
}
```

`self.managedObjectContext` is MOC B, connected to the same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator as MOC A (thread confinement pattern 1).

The TableViewController is a delegate of an `NSFetchedResultsController` reading data from MOC B.

I find that delegate methods `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` and `controllerDidChangeContent:` do NOT get called after receiving the notification from MOC A.

Would I have to refetch the data in MOC B's fetchedResultsController to see the new objects added in MOC A?

Answer (score 1):

devQry,

You have, of course, set the fetched results controller delegate? Without doing that, nothing can get called.

Andrew

Comment: yes, I have:

...      self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
   assert(self.fetchedResultsController.delegate == self);

....

Comment: I've also changed my call to mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:
to become:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notif];
        });

But, sadly, to no avail :(

Comment: I switched to the new (iOS 5++) NSMainQueueConcurrencyType and NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType MOCs, setting the background MOC's parentContext to the foreground MOC, getting rid of the notification and merge methods completely.
When calling 
[parentContext performBlock:^{
       NSError *ep = nil;
       if (![parentContext save:&ep]) {
           //...
       }
   }];
after saving in the background child context, everything works as expected.